# Generating Key/value (coulmn name/value) pairs from a MySQL call

Tags: php, mysql

My normal way of querying an SQL table (I'm using php) is by implementing the line below:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE SOME CONDITION") or die(mysql_error());
```

I would like to query in a way that returns key/value pairs where the key is the column name. Can anyone suggest an elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to read the row from the table.